# Taylor's diagrams package : set color of individual elements

Tags: color, diagrams, graphs

In [Paul Taylor's `diagrams` package](http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/), is it possible to set the color of specific elements in a diagram? If so, how?

I have tried using `\color{a_color}`. It changes the color of part of the diagram, but I never succeed in coloring specific elements of the graph.

For instance, in the following diagram,

```
    \begin{diagram}
            \bullet     &                       &   \bullet \\
            \dLink      &   \rdLink             &            \\
            \bullet     &                       &   \bullet
    \end{diagram}
```

I would like to color **only** the diagonal link `\rdlink` in red. I have tried

```
\begin{diagram}
            \bullet     &                                     &   \bullet \\
            \dLink      &  \color{red}  \rdLink \color{black} &            \\
            \bullet     &                                     & \bullet
\end{diagram}
```

but this leaves the graph uncolored. I have also tried

```
\begin{diagram}
            \bullet     &                                     &   \bullet \\
            \dLink      &  \color{red}  \rdLink               &            \\
            \bullet     &                                     & \bullet
\end{diagram}
```

which yields

[image]

beside making all the following diagram red too. Other combination of `\color{red}` and `\color{black}` yields similar somewhat erratic outcomes.

It looks like using `\color{a_color}` sets the color of the whole line, as well as the color of the later lines (in further diagrams too).

**Any idea how I could color a single element (say a link) of a single line?**

Comment: Have you considered one of the TikZ-based packages for drawing these kinds of diagrams? (Or PSTricks probably has packages, too.)

Comment: I don't think the package supports color; since the code is obfuscated, it's impossible to try and make it honor color choices.

Comment: Using a package with obfuscated code "maintained" by someone who expressly claims he has little to no time to devote to (La)TeX seems unwise....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you to switch to the powerful [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package which was built upon TikZ specifically for commutative diagrams. You can easily control the attributes for every element of yout diagrams:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\bullet\ar[d,dash]\ar[dr,red,dash] & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Given the above comments on why I should try alternatives to "diagrams", I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The package file [`diagrams.sty`](http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/diagrams.sty), found on the [webpage](http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/), does not define `\*Link` commands, therefore I have used `\*Line` instead (`\dLine` and `\rdLine`).

Analyzing the package is a very time consuming task, because the author obfuscated the internal macros.

But it seems that the approach of package `luacolor` works here. It does not insert specials, but sets the color via LuaTeX's attributes. Therefore the package requires LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagrams}
\usepackage{luacolor}

\begin{document}
  \begin{diagram}
    \bullet     &                       &   \bullet \\   
    \dLine      &  \color{red}\rdLine   &           \\
    \bullet     &                       &   \bullet
  \end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

For those who do not want to use [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd), `psmatrix` from the [`pst-node`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-node?lang=en) package works fine.

An example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{psmatrix}[nodesep = 10pt, colsep=3cm, rowsep=3cm]
        % % % %
         \CIRCLE & \CIRCLE\\
        \CIRCLE & \CIRCLE 
        % % % %
        \psset{linecolor = red}
        \ncline{-}{1,1}{2,2}
        \psset{linecolor = black}
        \ncline{-}{1,1}{2,1}
    \end{psmatrix}
$$

\end{document}
```

The result :

[image]